# C++ Reference Length Performance

Tags: c++, reference, complexity-theory

My question is simple, what is the performance loss due to reference length. I cannot explain myself but here is the sample:

between this

```
C* pC = m_a->m_b->m_c;
```

and this expression

```
C* pC = m_b->m_c;
```

I am asking this because I have a global class which has a Singleton pattern and holds everything. I am accessing all of its members from its members like this.

```
class Global
{
    A* a;
    X* x;
};

class A { B* b; };
class B { C* c; }; // etc

class X { Y* y; };
class Y { Z* z; };
class Z
{
    void foo() { Global::GetInstance()->a->b->c->foo(); }
}
```

Is this a good design? Any advice for this? I am having some trouble with this topic too [Qt Architecture Advice Needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838947/qt-architecture-advice-needed)

Comment: There's a simple way to answer this: run a benchmark. The answer will differ from architecture to architecture. And as a general rule, you shouldn't worry about minor performance issues like this unless you're having performance problems and profiling points it out as the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every -> operator is an indexed indirection, which costs a cycle or two, depending on the processor, and may be invisible if its pipeline is good enough.

However the real question here is 'compared to what?' What other implementation techniques are you considering for solving this problem? Unless you have a viable alternative your question is really meaningless.

Similarly the frequently-asked question about the relative efficiency of virtual and non-virtual functions is meaningless unless it takes into account how to get the same effect both ways. In the non-virtual case this amounts at least to an 'if' or 'switch', whose cost has to be added in to the comparison.